# Java Stream, how to check Map value for length

Tags: java, java-stream

I have  a stream expression that retrieves value from Map

```
String name = map.entrySet().stream()
                  .filter(map -> "fName".equalsIgnoreCase(map.getKey()))
                  .map(map -> map.getValue())
                  .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

I want to know how can I add a check to see if the map-value is blank or has some value in it.

So, if map-value for `fName` is blank throw exception
    else put in value in the variable `name`.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What type is `map`?

Comment: But `Map` will have only one unique `key` right? why do you need stream here?

Comment: Why not just check `map.get("fName").equals("")`?

Comment: Deadpool, Sweeper He wants to gather the values for "fName", "FNAME", ...

Comment: I think it's worth clarifying if the map really can contain multiple "fName" keys with different casings. If so, `Collectors.joining()` seems like it would not be the right option. If not, the solution is probably to normalise the map's keys, e.g. using `key.toLowerCase()` on every `get` or `put`.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the lambda with `{}` so it can have statements, such as throwing an exception.

```java
String name = map.stream()
    .filter(entry -> "fName".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey()))
    .map(entry -> {
        String v = entry.getValue();
        if(v == null || v.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("null or empty value: " + entry.getKey());
        }
        return v;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

In a single pipeline, you can deal with this using a `RuntimeException` cleanly. This would be using `Optional` to perform checks on the value of the map.

```
String name = inputMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> "fName".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey()))
        .map(entry -> Optional.ofNullable(entry.getValue())
                .filter(v -> !v.isEmpty())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Map value is blank!")))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what exactly blank means, but I think you can do

```
 String name = map.entrySet().stream()
                  .filter(map -> "fName".equalsIgnoreCase(map.getKey()))
                  .map(map ->(map.getValue()== null || map.getValue().length() ==0) ? throw new Exception(): map.getVaue())
                  .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: You cannot write `throw new Exception()` as an expression; it is a statement.